# Install PyVmomi on MAC

Tags: mac, python, vmware, ansible

I am running Mojave on my MAC.  I am trying to use the Ansible Vmware_guest module which requires "PyVmomi"  I have installed pyvmomi and pyvim via pip and brew.  They installed successfully on both without any errors, but Ansible is not picking it up.

According to my /usr/bin/python it says it is running 2.7 code.

Not sure where to go from here any suggestions?

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/cg/g1sjcv650119nxk2xdt2w6280000gn/T/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_BwxMqP/ansible_vmware_guest_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/vmware.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pyVim import connect
ImportError: No module named pyVim
```

Comment: You can run      python -c "help('modules')"     on the command line, it should show pyVim and pyVmomi in the list. If it doesn't, you installed the modules somewhere python can't find it.

Comment: As you can see they are both there.

python -c "help('modules')"

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

_elementtree        errno               pyVim               xdrlib
_functools          exceptions          pyVmomi             xml

Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type "modules spam" to search
for modules whose descriptions contain the word "spam".

Comment: Did you install pyVmomi on the remote host or on the Ansible controller? If you installed it on the controller you need to delegate the vmware_guest task to localhost.

Comment: This ansible script is being run on the localhost.  so in this case there is NO remote host.